# Setenv error message

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

When I opened up the Gnome command prompt, several lines of the message:

> No command 'setenv' found, did you mean command 'netenv' from 
>     package 'netenv' (command)

However, I have never used such command before. 
It's just I installed a software through Gnome.

Answer (score 4):

`setenv` is a [C shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell) command, but you're running bash which has no such command.

There are two major families of [unix shells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell): the Bourne family and the C family. Bash, the default shell on most Linux systems, is a member of the Bourne family (“bash” stands for “Bourne-again shell”). The C family has fallen into disuse, its features have now mostly been imitated and improved in bash and zsh.

You've clearly inserted some C shell instructions into one of your shell startup files (`.bashrc`, perhaps?). You'll need to undo that.

If you have C shell instructions and you need help translating them into Bourne syntax, feel free to ask here. The most important thing to know is that to set an environment variable in the C shell, you write

```
setenv VARIABLE_NAME "some value"
```

In a Bourne shell, you write this in `~/.profile` (or in `/etc/profile` if it's for all users):

```
export VARIABLE_NAME="some value"
```

Comment: That is strange, because I did use export function. I put in export VARIABLE =/usr/local/sac *newline* source ${VARIABLE}/bin/sacinit.csh onto the ~/.bashrc editor and saved it.I clearly did not use "sentenv" anywhere.

Comment: @GTyler That file you're including, `sacinit.csh`, is clearly a C shell (csh) file which calls `setenv`. Bash can't read it, it's in a wrong language. You need to source `sacinit.bash` or `sacinit.sh` if such is provided, or convert `sacinit.csh` to Bourne/bash syntax.

Comment: Changed that. Now I am getting bash: export: `1` not a valid identifier newline bash: export: `0` not a valid identifier

Comment: @GTyler: Changed what to what? Post the names and contents of all the files involved, we can't help you with so little detail.

Comment: it sounds like you are doing `export $FOO=bar` not `export FOO=bar` — including the dollar sign means it is trying to evaluate `$FOO`, which is not what you want.